# Finding acute angle between line and plane (Vectors)

Tags: vectors

This is a very very simple question about vectors:

To find the **acute** angle between a line and a plane, you use the formula

**cosx = (scalar product between normal of plane and directional vector of line)/(product of modulus of normal and directional vector)**

After that, do **90 degrees minus x** to get the answer.

(By the way, I realise that using sinx=.... would spare me the effort of minusing - but is that way recommended?)

In this question  of plane 2x-y+4z=9 and directional vector (10,5,-5),
after doing all the working, I get cosx= -0.089... and x=95.11 degrees.

[image]

But the question wants **acute** angle and 90-x gives me -5.1 degrees. What should I do? The answer is 5.1 deg but I don't see how 90-x gets me that...

NB: using sinx gives me -5.1 degrees straightaway.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, between the direction vector  $ v=(10,5,-5)$ and the normal vector $( 2,-1,4)$ the angle is not acute, in  fact it is obtuse (you can see that by a simple  plot). [image]

However as you are asking about the angle between a  line and a plane,  so the  you must take care of the orientation of the vectors you are working with.

In you case, to find the angle $ \theta $ you can do the following :
when finding $\cos x$, apply  $\arccos$ to find an angle  $\phi$. Then subtract $\phi $ from  $180$ to get    $ \alpha=180 - \phi$ . Now  $\theta =  90 - \alpha$.

Comment: But why do you subtract ϕ from 180 to get α then do 90-α? And if you get an angle that is straightaway acute, you don't need to do 180-x first?

Comment: Note that between the normal and the line passing through the plane we have two angles, one is acute and  the other is obtuse (unless the line is not in the plane, otherwise the  two angles are right).
 When using dot product to find  the angle between the line and the normal, in fact you are computing the angle   between the  normal  vector and the directing vector of the st line. Hence, either you would get the acute angle or the obtuse angle.

Comment: AS here you are searching for the acute one, you can get it from the result. If your result is acute so it is okay, otherwise  subtract the obtained angle from 180° .

Comment: Oh, so if the result is 90 to 180, then I got the obtuse one so 180-x gives me the acute one (then 90-theta). On the other hand, if I straightaway get an acute answer then I can assume I got the right answer then?

Comment: Exactly, this depends which angle you are searching for the acute or the obtuse . @user9856